# Spliting string of arithmetic operations in lua

Tags: function, split, lua, arguments, lua-table

The following is string of arithmetic operations in lua.

```
local str ='x+abc*def+y^z+10'
```

Can this string be splitted so that individual variables or numbers will appear? For example, say string `str` is splitted into table `s`. Then the output will be

```
s[1] = x
s[2] = abc
s[3] = def
s[4] = y
s[5] = z
s[6] = 10
```

The splitting is to be done with operators `+,-,*,\,^,%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also this simpler pattern:

```
local str ='x+(abc*def)+y^z+10'
for w in str:gmatch("%w+") do
        print(w)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.gmatch to iterate over your string.
Feel free to add other operators to the pattern.

Refer to https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1

```
local str ='x+abc*def+y^z+10'
local s = {}

for operand in str:gmatch('[^%+%*%^]+') do
  table.insert(s, operand)
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work when parentheses are used. For example `x+(abc*def)+y^z+10`

Comment: @Maths89 I know. Please read your question again. I don't see any parenthesis in there. My answer perfectly solves the described problem. I cannot read your mind.

Comment: Okay. No problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string.gmatch` to do what your looking for. you would use the pattern `%+%-%*%^/`

```
local str ='x+abc*def+y^z+10'
local s = {}
for value in str:gmatch("[%+%-%*%^/]*(%w*)[%+%-%*%^/]*") do
  s[#s + 1] = value
end
print(unpack(s))
```

Also not that if you need `\` as operator as shown in your question it would need to be escaped using an additional `\`.

Resourse for leaning more about lua patterns: [understanding_lua_patterns](https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:understanding_lua_patterns)

Comment: please note that unpack has been moved to table.unpack in Lua 5.2